# Interference between graphics card and wireless adapter

Tags: wireless-networking, interference, pci-express, displayport

I have a workstation (HP Z600) with a graphics card (NVidia Quadro FX 3800) that has a DVI connector and two displayport connectors, as well as a Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter.

When I only have a monitor connected to the DVI port, all is fine, but when I connect one to either of the displayports, the network connection becomes really bad. The way in which I test this is by pinging my local wireless access point, and I get a packet loss of around 90%.

I first thought this might be a software problem, so I started changing drivers, etc, and also switched between Linux and Windows, but the problems were very similar.

Then I started changing the location of the PCIe cards in the housing, and this made some difference, it looks like the further away the cards are from each other, the better it is. Which one is on top doesn't seem to matter much. In any case, even in the best configuration the ping is still very slow and the packet loss is 70%, so it is still not usable.

Does this sound familiar to anyone? I am principally asking this to solve my particular problem, but I would also be interested to hear hypotheses on what could be actually happening.

Finally, if this question is off-topic on this site, could you point me to a more appropriate one?

Comment: The question is border-line EE. Do you have any way of shielding one or both cards, or create a shield between them? If you could determine that shielding improves things, it would indicate the card gives off EMI, which would then help to narrow down the question. Problem is though that you'll need to formulate a specific 'engineering' question as pure 'repair' questions will be shut down quickly.

Comment: @RJR I understand, thanks. Could a sheet of aluminium foil wrapped in plastic serve as a shield?

Comment: Did the wireless card come with extension leads to locate the antennae further away?

Comment: @AndrewMorton It didn't, but I do have one lying around. I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

Take a long piece of AL  foil, wrap one end around the suspect aggressor card.
Use 3" by 9" foil.

Tape the other end (you need a number of square inches here, you are making a large-area capacitor) atop the metal case; the capacitance from foil to case/chassis is the RF shunting path for (assumed) Efield interference.

Aluminum foil has oxide surface, thus you can only use a CAPACITIVE energy transfer.